# Can't compare XXXX-XXXX integer format to text

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a database I have not created. In table tableA, there is a field fieldA defined as "long integer", and all of its values have the format "0000-0000" (with other numbers different than 0).

I have created another table with field fieldB, with the same kind of data of fieldA from tableA. I need to compare fieldB and fieldA (WHERE fieldA = fieldB), but I can't.

I can't define fieldB as "long integer" because then I can't input values like "0000-0000". I really don't understand how the guy who created the database managed to do so in fieldA.

If I define it as "short text" and then try "WHERE fieldA = fieldB", I get a type mismatch error.

If I define it as "short text" and then try "WHERE CStr(fieldA) = fieldB" or "WHERE Str(fieldA) = fieldB" no rows are returned. Not even a blank row, looks like an error.

I can't modify tableA to change the type of fieldA to string due to irrelevant reasons.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create FieldB as Long and assign it the Format: 0000-0000

You can enter, say, 75522 and it will be displayed as: 0007-5522

Comment: It doesn't work. This way I can enter the data to fieldB, but I still can't compare it to fieldA. Nothing is returned, not even a blank row, something is wrong. There's no mask in fieldA, and the data comes from a relationship with another table, if that's relevant.

Comment: If the old FieldA is a Long, and your new FieldB is as well, records will be returned if one or more values are found in both tables. If not, something else is going on.